# Android Discard SSL Certificate

Tags: android, ssl

Is there any way to discard the SSL Certificate when requesting a response from a website? I've managed to do this fairly easily with iPhone, but haven't had any luck finding an analogous solution for Android. I'm using the Apache HTTP classes; HttpPost, HttpResponse, HttpClient, etc.

The iPhone version of this app uses the line [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO] which seems to do the trick. Does anyone know how to do the same with Android?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'discard'? The peer certificate doesn't get stored anywhere permanently.

Comment: When I get an HttpResponse after calling HttpClient.execute and posting my data to the server, an error shows up as "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate"

I had a similar problem with the iPhone version of this app, but circumvented it by using the following line:

[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];

Is there any similar method/function for Android?

Comment: `[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]` doesn't 'discard a certificate'. By its name, it just sets an insecure configuration that prevents the peer certificate from being validated. I would have a look at installing your own `X509TrustManager` into your own `SSLContext`, but make sure the result is still secure: don't just accept any old certificate. At least ask the user, if the certificate isn't valid, isn't trusted, has expired, etc.